# Force Webpack to use ES6 syntax in react-app bundle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

### My aim would be to have `ES6` syntax (or latest one) in my entire react-app built.

I've already managed to avoid polyfills in my own code by omitting some babel dependencies (such as [`@babel/preset-env`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env)).

My bundled file does however hold, by most part, `ES5` syntax. I'm assuming that babel (or webpack?) is polyfilling react and webpack's [runtime](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/manifest/#runtime) to `ES5` for browser compatibility.

Another option could be that webpack's runtime is natively supposed to use `ES5` and cannot be converted to `ES6` (current sustained possibility, see answer).

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [ "@babel/preset-react" ]
  }
```

and here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [ path.join(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules" ],
    alias: {
      react: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules", "react")
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({ template: "./src/index.html" })
  ],
};
```

I am not using `create-react-app` but my own boilerplate and configuration.

My `index.js`, `app.js`, `index.html`, `styles.css` are into the `./src` folder.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Even though the question has been officially answered, my post remains active and attentive on updates concerning Webpack’s use of ES6 syntax in app bundles.

Comment: @Liam I have accepted your suggestion although, as the other answer mentions, webpack still can't use es6 sytax throughout entire bundle.
When I say that webpack isn't using es6 maybe it is actually using es6 but `var` keyword is prefered over `let` and `const` ?

Comment: Here is the output I get https://github.com/rattleSSnake/Factorization-Calculator/blob/gh-pages/app.bundle.js after running `npm run build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using `@babel/preset-env` then your code shouldn't change by default. Only react should get transpiled to es5 (mostly JSX transpilation). You are probably mentioning the boilerplate code added by webpack which can be in es5.

you can use `optimization: { minimize: false }` in your webpack config, to see your bundle better.

These boilerplates by webpack are called [runtime](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/manifest/).

There is no way to force webpack to use a set of features, but you can force it to **NOT** use a set of features threw [`output.environment.*`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment). For example with the code below you are saying to not use `const` in the runtime code.

```js
...

output: {
    environment: {
        const: false
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I’ll accept your answer although it doesn’t really solve my issue since there is no way to force webpack to use ES6. Thanks for clarifying this